# configure SMTP in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, smtp

We successfully migrated our windows domain and servers to Windows Azure (DC, Exchange, Labtech etc). But now we're facing a challenge with sending mail from the websites trough a contact form.

It seems Azure had no built-in smtp service we can use. So we want to use our own Exchange server. Since we have no programming skills ourselves, and our website is built with php, we have no idea how to configure this. Any help would be welcome and appreciated.

Best regards,
Mischa

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a third party like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/)

Comment: Stating that there is a "good reason" without explaining that reason is not very useful.  Would you care to elaborate?